# How do i setup custom font

Tags: swift, embedded-resource, uifont

I have checked every single guide (including Apple developer) of how to implement custom fonts into your app. And nothing works.

Here's what i have setup:

1: The files are added in a sub folder called Fonts in Resources.

2: The files are added in `Copy Bundle Resources`

3: The file names are added in `Info.plist` with the end tag of `.ttf`

4: The files are added to the Target Membership.

What i have also tried:

1: Added `Application fonts resource path` as "Fonts" in `Info.plist`

2: Added the files to `Copy files phase` in `build phases` under the correct target.

How do i call them?

```
enum Font: String {
    case robotoMedium = "Roboto-Medium"
    case robotoLight = "Roboto-Light"
    case robotoRegular = "Roboto-Regular"
    case robotoMediumItalic = "Roboto-MediumItalic"
    case robotoThinItalic = "Roboto-ThinItalic"
    case robotoBoldItalic = "Roboto-BoldItalic"
    case robotoLightItalic = "Roboto-LightItalic"
    case robotoBlackItalic = "Roboto-BlackItalic"
    case robotoBold = "Roboto-Bold"
    case robotoThin = "Roboto-Thin"
    case robotoBlack = "Roboto-Black"
    case robotoRegularItalic = "Roboto-RegularItalic"
    func withSize(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: self.rawValue, size: size)!
    }
}
```

Font is set by using:
`Font.robotoRegular.withSize(size: 24)`

Some debugging:

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames
        {
            print("\(family)")
            for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
            {
                print("== \(names)")
            }
        }
```

In this print my fonts are not added.

Please don't just read the title and say "duplicate" because it's really not. I have checked every single solution out there.

Comment: you can double check what the _actual_ font-names are, the font name should be the fully specified name of the font ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619041-init)), and that is rarely identical to the _actual_ files' names – and that could cause that the fonts are not loaded after all; if you have concerns, you can use [Apple's idea](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app) to print out the actual fonts' names on the console and compare; and make sure the fonts are parts of the current target.

Comment: Printed it, and it's not in there :/

Comment: Have you tried setting the font this way: yourLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 24).  If it works then at least the set up is correct.

Comment: @omar That created a nil value and goes back to system font

Comment: @ElTomato Because i have written down everything i've done and hopefully someone out there have had the same problem and can suggest an solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out the problem. Which seems like an Xcode bug?

I noticed that if i first put the Font onto a label in a storyboard (i'm doing everything programmatically). It was actually loaded into the font family. I don't know why i have to add it in a storyboard. But as dumb as it is here is my solution:

[image]

Guess it's the most ugly solution i have ever seen, but it works, and i can't find another way.